# MVC JSON Data Object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I am trying to get data from the following class:

```
 public class SalesData
    {
        public string RepName { get; set; }

        public string DateString { get; set; }

        public decimal TotalSales { get; set; }

        public decimal RepSales { get; set; }
    }

    public static class SalesDataBuilder
    {
        public static List<SalesData> GetCollection()
        {
            return new List<SalesData>
            {
                new SalesData
                {
                    RepName = "Nancy Davolio",
                    DateString = "Aug 2010",
                    TotalSales = 10458,
                    RepSales = 2015
                },

                new SalesData
                {
                    RepName = "Nancy Davolio",
                    DateString = "Sept 2010",
                    TotalSales = 21598,
                    RepSales = 6003
                },  };
        }
```

Using Json in my controller, I tried the following:

```
   public JsonResult IndexJson()
        {
            IEnumerable<SalesData> person = (from e in SalesData

                                                    select new SalesData
                                                {
                                                    RepName = e.RepName,
                                                    RepSales = e.RepSales 
                                                });
            return Json(person);
        }
```

Certainly I am doing something wrong, being very new to json.  I would appreciate your suggestions.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: so... what is your question/issue?

Comment: The jsonResult in the controller does not work!

Comment: How doesn't it work?  Can you not consume this on the client side?  Is there an error or compilation problem?  There is no question here.

Comment: Forgive the question, but does this code even build? Should it read "(from e in GetCollection()"?

Comment: The code does not build.  I used    return Json(SalesDataBuilder.GetCollection()); it works in Ajax.  What I am trying to do is to use json as data source for Kendo grid.

Comment: First this is to fire up Fiddler and see what response is being returned from the ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't even compile. You never call the `SalesDataBuilder.GetCollection` method. Try like this:

```
public ActionResult IndexJson()
{
    IEnumerable<SalesData> person = 
        from e in SalesDataBuilder.GetCollection()
        select new SalesData
        {
            RepName = e.RepName,
            RepSales = e.RepSales
        };
    return Json(person, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Notice that I am passing `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` to the Json method which is necessary if you are invoking this action using the GET verb.